# Lotus Notes - Add twistie in uncategorized view column using formula

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I am an experienced Notes developer but for the life of me can't remember how to add a twistie to a column value via Formula language instead of categorizing the column.

I can only remember it has something to do with adding "\" in the formula however this is not working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is an example of my code:

@If(@Contains(part; "Complete"; "Complete" + "\\" + part; part) 
or
@If(@Contains(part; "Complete"; "Complete" + "//" + part; part)

Please note that I do not want the entire column to be categorized but rather, a twistie should only become available if a document's part has the word "Complete" in it.

Much appreciated everyone.

Comment: But what shut happen with the doc when you have this twisty in the view. you can't extant the doc, because its not categorized. do you like to mark the doc?

Comment: Same question: What should this twisty do, when there is no category to open???

Answer (score 0):

What you remember is how to make **subcategories**. The column must be already categorized.